# Table did not continue to second page.. DOMPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I'm just a beginner in using DOMPDF w/ php... I'm having problems with page break in tables.,
table did not continue to second page..

I'm running Win7, PHP Version 5.3.8, DOMPDF_0-6-0_beta3
I've already added `page-break-after:always;` in table styles.

Comment: It would help to see the HTML you used and the resulting PDF.

Comment: Also, is [this](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=524) related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved it by removing form method and making sure table is not within another table..

Answer (score 0):

you can try `table-layout:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by taking the Table out of the "Header" section and DOMPDF sorted the rest out. Header sections don't wrap like the body of an HTML view does.

Comment: I also had table-layout:fixed as mentioned by @Rishi